# Word mergefield wildcard not correctly matching

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge, wildcards, code

Below is my mergefield code:

**{ IF { MERGEFIELD Subs_State } = "GA" "blah blah" "{ IF { MERGEFIELD CEOrgStates } = "*GA*" "blah blah" ""} "}**

I'm pulling records from a MS Access db. My goal is to check whether a record has Subs_State field matching "GA", or the CEOrgStates has the word "GA" (some records have stuff like "|FL|CA|GA|CT|KY|" (no quotes)).

When I merged the docs, Word doesnt seem to be able to match with the wildcards: If I use and compare "*GA" (fields ending with GA), it works; however, the double wildcards "*GA*" dont seem to work at all.

Here are the things I’ve tried:

- Have data in lowercase, then compare with lowercase
- Have data in lowercase, convert to and then compare with uppercase
- Do the opposite of the above 2 with uppercase data
- Use “*GA*” and “*ga*” (no pipe)
- Use different delimiters

Nothing seems to work with the double wildcard matching. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double wildcards don't work in Word is my understanding?

Could you use an AND( (ga* , *ga) type thing??

Yep: NO DOUBLES is confirmed here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33874436/string-comparison.aspx

Comment: Your asking a questions about the subject of the question.  This would better be a comment than an answer.  You do answer one of your questions, but not the other.